# Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

issue with AKS
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided, try setting `KUBERNETES_MASTER` environment variable

```
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.credentials.kube_config.0.host
    client_certificate     = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.credentials.kube_config.0.client_certificate)
    client_key             = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.credentials.kube_config.0.client_key)
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.credentials.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)

  }
}

resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress" {
  name = "nginx-ingress-controller"
  namespace = "default"
  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart      = "nginx-ingress-controller"

  set {
    name  = "service.type"
    value = "LoadBalancer"
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the config i am successfully using:

```
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.fqdn

    client_certificate     = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_admin_config.0.client_certificate)
    client_key             = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_admin_config.0.client_key)
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_admin_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in AWS EKS. Maybe it will be helpful for anybody who has the EKS issue and found this thread:

- "Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable"
- also "Error: Get
  "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/aws-auth":
  dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused"

What helped was changing from:

```
  host                   = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.this.token
```

to

```
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.this.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.this.certificate_authority.0.data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.this.token
```

Interesting that the first approach worked during a few hours after cluster creating

Just in cese:

```
data "aws_eks_cluster" "this" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_name
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "this" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_name
}
```

Comment: WHAT FILE ARE YOU TALKING ABOUT?